# How can I create the same record X amount of times in my seed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails (4.0.0) and Ruby (2.0.0) and wanted to know how to give each user the same book ten times. So first, I create my three Users:

```
user1 = User.create(name: "Fred")
user2 = User.create(name: "Bob")
user3 = User.create(name: "Ron")
```

Now I want to give all three users one book ten times to test my application. So I start out like this:

```
book = Book.create(title: "My Book")
```

After I get lost on how to do the `each` and assigning the users. Do you know how to? Mass assignment security doesn't matter in this situation, just need the data for view testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
User.all.find_each do |user|
  10.times { |i| user.books << Book.create!(title: "Book number #{i}") }
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This will look through all your users, then loop 10 times for each, creating a book each time (therefore creating 10 books).

```
[user1, user2, user3].each do |user|
  10.times do |i|
    Book.create!(title: "Book ##{i}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `without_protection` if you want to skip the mass_assignment protection

```
[user1, user2, user3].each do |user|
  10.times do |i|
    Book.create!({title: "Book ##{i}"}, :without_protection => true)
  end
end
```